# Node and React multer path is undefined when except of uploading image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, controller, multer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4nRH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRPD2.png)

**React code**

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({
         pSellingPrice: "",
    pImage: "",
})
 const inputImgs = useRef();


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let getRandomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19999999);

    //Insert data to database

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("pImage", inputImgs.current.files[0]);
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value));
    formData.append("pId", getRandomKey);
    formData.append("pIsActive", 1);

    //Post api
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/api/products/product/addProduct",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        },
        {
          headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
       console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

****form****

          <form onSubmit={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e)}}> 
                 <input
                    type="number"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="formrow-inputZip"
                    name="pSellingPrice"
                    value={data.pSellingPrice}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
                    required
                  />

             <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <label for="formFile" class="form-label">
                        Choose Product Image
                      </label>
                      <input
                        class="form-control"
                        ref={inputImgs}
                        type="file"
                        id="formFile"
                        name="pImage"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
```

**Node code**

*product.Router.js*

```
const {createProduct}  = require("./Product.controller");
const router = require("express").Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./image/productImage",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
}).single("pImage");

router.post("/addProduct", upload, createProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

**product.Controller.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const {addProduct}= = require("./product.service");
module.exports = {
      createProduct: (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const body = req.body;
    let image = req.file.path;

    console.log(image + "img");
    image = image.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    body.pImage = image;
    console.log(body.pImage);
    addProduct(body, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: 0,
          message: "Database connection error",
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        data: results,
      });
    });
  },
}
```

**product.service.js**

```
const pool = require("../../../config/database");
module.exports = {
  addProduct: (data, callBack) => {
    console.log(data);
    const query = `INSERT INTO products (pSellingPrice,pImage) VALUES
     ('${data.pSellingPrice}'
     ,'${data.pImage.slice(19)}')`;
    console.log(query);

    pool.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return callBack(error);
      }

      return callBack(null, results);
    });
  },
}
```

I tried to use react with Node for uploading image to database.. I used Multer library for that purpose. It works perfectly. According to client requirement sometimes no need to insert image from form. default image should use for that when image display. I cant submit form excepting image upload. I tried few ways , but couldn't solve-out. My backend gains some path issue in **product.controller.js** line **25** . when it storing database automatically make path. when request is done , uploaded image will be saved in local path at backend.. Those are the resources . please someone help me to except image uploading from form submit.

Note :- Above mentioned the error message images